# Vlookup from 2 possible entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an invoice, where the stock number can be a long format or a short format, but both being for the same product, for example:
124573 | 2100001245733 = Brown Blanket. I need to know if I type any one of those numbers into the cell, that the description Brown Blanket will come up.

If someone knows VBA for this, it would be great.

I don't know if I am explaining it properly, but assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this. If the last 5 characters are always your unique code, you can simply use:

```
=RIGHT(A1,5)
```

And this will get you the unique code. Then simply use that in your vlookup search (assuming your unique ID is in A1, and your table is in Sheet2, from column A to column B:

```
=vlookup(RIGHT(A1,5),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Keep in mind that this will be searching for TEXT, not numbers, so your table column A will need to be text too. You can fix this by either formatting that table to be text, or something like this:

```
=VALUE(vlookup(RIGHT(A1,5),Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

In the future please provide more information regarding how your data is laid out and what you want your results to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VLOOKUP
First make your lookup table like this (first row is just a header)
Let's say I put it at E1:H4
ShortNm LongNm         Result
124573  2100001245733   Brown Blanket
999999  2100009999993   Green Blanket
888888  2100008888883   Red Blanket

Then create a "type in here" cell. Let's say at A1,
then your Result cell at B1 (or whereever)
Here is the formula to use at B1
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$G$4,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A1,G11,2,FALSE)),"")
which basically tries both possiblities

Cheers,
Dave